# If $N'\subset N$ and $[G:N']=[G:N]=2$, then $N'=N$ for infinite $G$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $G$ be a group, and $N,N'$ subgroups. I'm working on a proof, where I want to show that $N\triangleleft G$. In this proof I have shown that $N'\triangleleft G$, $N'\subset N$ and $[G:N']=[G:N]=2$. Intuitively, I thought I could conclude that $N'=N$. However, I am in doubt now. This implication is trivial for finite $G$ (follows directly from Lagrange's theorem), but I don't know how I could proof this for the case $G$ is infinite. This made me doubt whether this is even true.

Using the identity $[G:N']=[G:N]\cdot[N:N']$ also does not seem to work since it assumes $G$ to be finite (right?). **EDIT 2** Following the comments, this seems to be [true](https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Index_is_multiplicative) for infinite $G$ also, so this proves the claim.

**EDIT** It might be important to note I need this to proof that a subgroup of index 2 is normal, so I cannot use this fact!

Is this true? Is it trivial and am I missing something? How would I proof this claim?

I tried searching this site already but I couldn't find anything related.

Comment: the identity you write is true for arbitrary group $G$ with finite index subgroups $N'\subset N$. Actually, using cardinal multiplication, it's true for arbitrary groups $N'\subset N\subset G$.

Comment: Hint: What does index $2$ mean in terms of cosets and partitions?  Can you write them in this case and look at their containment properties?

Comment: @YCor: okay, that would make the question a lot simpler. In my syllabus the identity is only proved for finite $G$. Is it also simple to prove if for infinite $G$? Would you have a reference or hint?

Comment: @MichaelBurr: this would imply $G=N\dot\cup G\setminus N=N'\dot\cup G\setminus N'$, but wouldn't it (a priori) still be posibble that $N\neq N'$

Comment: @MichaelBurr I see what you mean: the right and left cosets are the same thus $N\triangleleft G$ but the idea of this proof (of this exercise) is to come up with another proof for this. Thanks anyways!

Comment: That actually wasn't the direction that I was heading.  I posted an answer below to clarify my hint.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $[G:N]=2$, $N$ has two cosets in $G$.  In particular, fix $g\in G\setminus N$, then the two cosets are $N$ and $gN$.  Since $[G:N']=2$, $N'$ also has two cosets in $G$.  Moreover, since $N'\subset N$, $(G\setminus N)\subset (G\setminus N')$.  Therefore, $g\in G\setminus N'$ and the two cosets of $N'$ are $N'$ and $gN'$.

Since $N'\subset N$, $gN'\subset gN$.  However, since the cosets form a partition, $G\setminus N=gN$ and $G\setminus N'=gN'$.  Therefore, we have $gN\subset gN'$ from the argument above.  Therefore, $gN'=gN$.

We observe that the multiplication by $g$ map $\mu_g:G\rightarrow G$, $\mu_g(g')=gg'$ is a bijection.  Since, $gN=gN'$, so $N=N'$.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification of your hint! This seems the easiest way to prove it

Answer (score 2):

The key result that you need is that, if $T$ and $U$ are complete sets right coset representatives of $N'$ in $N$ and of $N$ in $G$, respectively, then $TU = \{tu : t \in T, u \in U \}$ is a complete set of coset representatives of $N'$ in $G$. The proof is reasonably straightforward.

Comment: Thank you! The proof is straightforward indeed.